Refresh Multistepform after time is up
I have a form-page where I added three components and each time the user clicks on the button it goes to the next step. However, the user has an amount of time to fill out the form and if the time is up the page refreshes (goes back to step 1). I stepped in a issue that every time the time is up the user ends at the final step instead of going back to previous.
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import { useActionState } from "react";
import { useFormStatus } from "react-dom";
import Step1 from "@/app/components/StepOne";
import Step2 from "@/app/components/StepTwo";
import Step3 from "@/app/components/StepThree";

const defaultState = {
  step: 0,
  elfCount: undefined,
  elfs: [],
};

const handleStep = (prev, formData) => {
  if (prev.step === 0) {
    //object destructuring
    return { ...prev, step: prev.step + 1, elfCount: formData.get("elfCount") };
  }
  if (prev.step === 1) {
    const elfs = Array.from({ length: prev.elfCount }, (_, i) => ({
      name: formData.get(`name_${i}`),
      email: formData.get(`email_${i}`),
    }));


    return { ...prev, step: prev.step + 1, elfs };
  }
};

export default function Form() {

  const [state, formAction] = useActionState(handleStep, defaultState);
  const status = useFormStatus();

  const resetForm = () => {
    formAction(new FormData()); 
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Julenisse Gaveuddeling</h1>
      {state.step === 0 && <Step1 formAction={formAction} />}
      {state.step === 1 && (
        <Step2 formAction={formAction} elfCount={state.elfCount} resetForm={resetForm}/>
      )}
      {state.step === 2 && <Step3 data={state} formStatus={status} />}
    </>
  );
}

Step 2 Component
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function StepTwo({ formAction, elfCount, resetForm }) {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(5); 
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (timeLeft <= 0) {
      alert("Tiden er udløbet");
      resetForm(); // Nulstil state til at starte fra Step 1
      router.push("/form"); 
      return;
    }

    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLeft((prevTime) => prevTime - 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [timeLeft, resetForm, router]);

  return (
    <form>
      <p className="timer">
        Tid tilbage: {Math.floor(timeLeft / 60)}:{String(timeLeft % 60).padStart(2, '0')}
      </p>
      {Array.from({ length: elfCount }, (_, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <label htmlFor={`name_${i}`}>
            Navn
            <input
              className="text-blue-800 my-2 mx-2"
              type="text"
              name={`name_${i}`}
            />
          </label>
          <label htmlFor={`email_${i}`}>
            Email
            <input
              className="text-blue-800 my-2 mx-2"
              type="email"
              name={`email_${i}`}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}
      <button type="submit" formAction={formAction}>
        Næste
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}


It doesn't look like you're resetting the step back to 0 in the useEffect hook.

when you call resetForm with an empty FormData, in handleStep, prev.step is still 0, so it adds one step and sends you back to step 2 instead of step 1.
you should check if formData.step is not defined, the reset state to defaultState to go back to step 1 (or step with index 0)
